# Access page controls in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web application in VS 2008. I used jquery for validation of different Forms and used it for other purposes. In VS 2008 I get the IDs of page controls in jquery like Ctl001_.... , but now I have upgraded the application to VS 2010 and now all my page controls are giving error in jquery because its changed its ID there as ContentBody_....., I can not convert all these to the new prefix ContentBody_.... because on the server my project runs on .Net Framework 3.5 and there the IDs are with the Prefix of Ctl001_...., 
can any one tell me a way that I can easily get control's ID in jquery without depending on the .Net Framework.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ClientID` property of the asp controls. `$('#<%=textBox1.ClientID%>')` would return `$('#ctl001_textBox1')` or whatever asp decides to rename it.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply.but I got 'Undefined' Error when I tried this  var _popup;

        function showpopup() {
            var txtMessage = $('#<%=txtMessage.ClientID%>').val();

            alert(txtMessage);
            if (txtMessage == 'What would you like to share with the world?') {
                parent.showMessage('Please add some comments to post!'); return false;
            }
            else {
                this._popup = $('#ContentBody_pnlPopup');
                this._popup.show();
            }
        }

Comment: can you tell where exactly the error occurs? if at all possible, can you also paste the generated source of the `txtMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ends with selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

```
jQuery('[id$="_textBox1"]');
```

Comment: BTW, arvil solution I like better, but it's good to have choice. ;-)